# Space complexity of merging two sorted arrays of length m and n

Tags: c++, arrays

I saw the function to do so in geeks for geeks where the two input arrays and the third array of length m+n were passed as parameters and the space complexity was given O(m+n).But how can it be this as the third array of length m+n was passed as a parameter and was not declared inside the function?Shouldn't it be O(1)?

Comment: To use the function you need an extra m+n regardless of where it is allocated. I've <expletive deleted>ed up more than my share of Big-O questions through the years, but O notation is measuring algorithms, not functions, so I doubt you can dodge the O(m+n) needed by an algorithm by allocating it outside a function and passing it in.

Comment: You are right. You may find a detailed answer in [Does space complexity analysis usually include output space?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83574/does-space-complexity-analysis-usually-include-output-space).

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic complexity of an algorithm is the amount of space/time the algorithm requires when viewed in isolation. The algorithm requires the third array's space exclusively hence its counted as its complexity.

Besides theoretical definitions of asymptotic complexity, irrespective of where the array is declared when the function is running it requires those `m+n` units of space.